# ¿Cómo exportar a excel por medio ajax?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

La solución que tengo actualmente para que me funciones utilice windows.location, quiero con ajax para obtener una repuesta y asi implementar un loading que se vea cuando inicie la descarga y desaparesca cuando termine con un mensaje de alerta.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se pueden descargar archivos vía Ajax.

Comment: @jasilva no, no es posible. Esa librería es un "ajax-like". Imagina que sí se pudiese descargar archivos vía ajax. Al entrar a un sitio web, el sitio **sin consultarte** podría disparar acciones de descarga de archivos maliciosos a tu computadora y quizás ejecutarlos o engañarte para que los ejecutes. Esto sucedía en 199x y antes, y al entrar a ciertos sitios tu computadora podía literalmente ser formateada.

Comment: @jasilva No, no es posible. El propio autor del plugin lo afirma. Usar un truco con un Iframe no es igual a una descarga por ajax.

Comment: @jasilva Ajax te permite hacer algo que este plugin no puede y es que si la descarga necesita autenticación y no estas usando cookies puedes incluir un header "Autorization" y te autenticas. Con un Iframe no puedes lograr eso  tienes que poner los tokens en la query lo cual no es seguro y queda plasmado en las trazas de los proxys por lo que tienes que crear tokens de autenticación de corta duración y cambiar la implementación del backend para que funcione. El plugin se queda corto en este aspecto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si estas implementando webapi vas a tener que devoler un FileResult o crearte un ActionResult custom

[Export To Excel in MVC](https://jamessdixon.wordpress.com/2010/05/12/export-to-excel-in-mvc/)

Veras como crea un `ExcelResult` donde asigna el `Response` asignado el `ContentType` y tambien pasarias el render del excel que quieres enviar

```
public class ExcelResult : ActionResult
{
    public string XMLStream { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }


    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {

        context.HttpContext.Response.Buffer = true;

        context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();

        context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);

        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

        context.HttpContext.Response.Write(XMLStream);
    }

}
```

Respecto a ajax, **no se pueden descargar archivos vía ajax**. Existen librerías que simulan el efecto de descargar archivos con ajax tal como [jquery.fileDownload](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload)